Which command shows all previously used terminal commands?
Which command can be used to get a list of all previously used terminal commands?
With the command history, we can get a list of all previously used commands in the terminal or Visual Studio Code. Is there any other shorthand or command to get the command history?

You can use the following commands:

Get-History: Gets the session history, that is, the list of commands entered during the current session.

cat (Get-PSReadlineOption).HistorySavePath | select -Last 100: Gets the last 100 commands from the history file. Or use cat (Get-PSReadlineOption).HistorySavePath | more to get the entire command history.

Press Ctrl+R: Interactively search through the command history.


